# Fetch external API using .NET with basic authentication and store data in SQL Server database using EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, entity-framework-core

I'm not getting the data into my SQL Server database. Hope someone can guide me. Thanks.

In Visual Studio 2022:

`Program`:

```
using APItoSQL1.Model;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

async Task<List<Party>> FetchParties()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "username:password");

        var response = await client.GetAsync("url");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Party>>();
        return data;
    }

    async Task SaveParties(List<Party> parties)
    {
        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            context.Parties.AddRange(parties);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    var parties = await FetchParties();
    await SaveParties(parties);
}
```

My `DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DbContext = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext;

namespace APItoSQL1.Model
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Party> Parties { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Server="myservername";Initial Catalog="myDBname";Integrated Security=True";
        }
    }
}
```

Class `Party`:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace APItoSQL1.Model
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "parties")]
    public class Party
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "isOrganization")]
        public bool IsOrganization { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "primeName")]
        public string PrimeName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "givenName")]
        public string GivenName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Have I missed something? I'd appreciate any help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing "classic" Entity Framework and EF Core:

Remove the reference to EntityFramework from your project, and remove this using:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public DbSet<Party> Parties { get; set; }
```